# UE5 When im creating SphereTrace its not following points of my actor

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

Firstly im spawning sword and attaching it to my character skeletal mesh to a one of sockets i created

```
SwordActor = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<ASwordActorClass>(SActorClass);
SwordActor->AttachToComponent(PCharacter->GetMesh(), FAttachmentTransformRules::SnapToTargetNotIncludingScale, FName("Sword"));
```

Next, im calling in my sword actor tick Sphere trace multi.

```
void ASwordActorClass::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

if (true)
{
FTransform StartSocketTransform = SwordMeshComponent->GetSocketTransform(FName("Start"), ERelativeTransformSpace::RTS_World);
FTransform EndSocketTransform = SwordMeshComponent->GetSocketTransform(FName("End"), ERelativeTransformSpace::RTS_World);

FVector Start = StartSocketTransform.GetLocation();
FVector End = EndSocketTransform.GetLocation();

UE_LOG(LogTemp, Display, TEXT("End Vector: %s"), *End.ToString());

TArray<FHitResult> Hits;
bool bHit = UKismetSystemLibrary::SphereTraceMulti(GetWorld(), Start, End, 10, UEngineTypes::ConvertToTraceType(ECC_Visibility), false, TArray<AActor*>(), EDrawDebugTrace::ForDuration, Hits, true);

FVector Direction = (End - Start).GetSafeNormal();
FRotator Rotation = Direction.Rotation() + FRotator(90, 0, 0);

}
```

So my Sphere is not completely following my sword. I think it can be related to the way im attaching actor to my mesh, But i dont know the solution.

The second sword on screen seems to work fine when its not attached
You can see how it look like here:

[Sphere trace visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHt2P.jpg)

Tried to using arrows instead of sockets and it changes literally nothing and used SweepMultiByChannel.

I could instead of sphere trace add an capsule component or listen to hit event of mesh but i do rather have sphere trace or sweep multi by channel.

Comment: Does the Sword Mesh have sockets with the corresponding names?

Comment: @Raildex Yes of course

Answer (score -1):

i suggest making a capsule collision around the sword and then get all overlapped actors over the capsule, loop and throw into an array then deal damage to all actors in the array and then clear it for the next attack.  using tick etc will cause lows fps and sometimes not detect the traces correctly IMO overlapped actors is more accurate and wont break if the games at 1fps or 120 ...